# How do I fix a "E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found." error?

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

I tried updating my packages from the terminal and this is what I got:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
```

What does this mean? I'm using the United States mirror an I've tried using the main server for the mirror and I keep getting the same result is this because there are no updates?

Comment: Can you show your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: See the answer for [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338915/how-to-fix-apt-get-install-f-apt-transport-https-error-404-not-found), it solved the issue for me on Debian Stretch.

Answer (score 188):

SirCharlo said in the duplicate of this question:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

I tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me in Debian Squeeze.

Comment: How is this possible? He can't able to connect to the internet.

Comment: Sadly, this won't work if your apt cache is too far out of date. Now I'm stuck in a "hole in the bucket" problem :(

Comment: @Owen why not just disable the `https` repo until you can update your cache?

Comment: @Owen that would allow someone else to provide a replacement or trojan wrapper around any unsigned package.

Answer (score 8):

in my case, find all the source in .list file, eg:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

some source in the list are forced using https:// even if you changed it into http:// it will redirected to https://

the solutions is :

1. backup and **remove the https source** first
2. then **run apt-get update**
3. run **sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https**
4. **restore the https source**

Comment: so you're saying you should update over an insecure connection?

Comment: this was the only solution that worked for me on kali linux

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem on fresh OrangePi image. Swapping https to http didn't help. Finally I created a symlink to http with name https and was able to perform apt-get update. The first thing to install was apt-transport-https than I re-run the update.

Comment: The OrangePI seems actually to still have this problem, could you precisely explain what do you mean by a "symlink" in this case please ?

Comment: @dlewin `cd /usr/lib/apt/methods` then `ln -s http https` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was the Opera browser in **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list** was, it was wrote:

```
https//:
```

but the correct is:

```
https://
```

So I fix the line this way:

```
deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
```

and all solved!

Answer (score 1):

My error read method driver `/usr/lib/apt/methods/htttp` and after reading here and trying all offerings, I was about to give up when I noticed that the `http` had one extra `t`.

I went to did this:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/source.list
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to find all instances of `htttp`.

removed the extra t

Saved (twice to make sure the bugger took it)

And viola, problem solved.

Guess that means I need to REALLY Read the error messages as I had been skimming over them.  Lesson learned.  that won't happen again

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a very old thread, but in my case the sources.list file was missing "http." in the address. (ie, http://kali.org vs http://http.kali.org) I discovered this when comparing two VM's in my environment. Not sure where the error came from, but replacing that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before, in my case the problem was in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Make sure there are no quotation marks `''` or `""`:

```
deb "http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick partner (Source Code)"
```

Remove quotes and change those lines to:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick partner (Source Code)
```

Also, as @arhimed suggests, make sure the protocol is well-formed: `http://`

Comment: Everything is in good form any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

look for https links in /etc/apt/sources.list
check if http link of the same link works. if it does then replace http with https and enjoy.
otherwise install sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https as said in the above answer by Damiön la Bagh

Answer (score 0):

My comments here aren't directly related to the OP's question, but since this page comes up in google's first result when searching `E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.` which is the error I was originally trying to solve, I am adding some information which helped me solve my problem.

I happen to be on an ethernet network which contains a "firewall" type device that redirects an unknown computer's web traffic to a webpage that requires you the "agree" to the terms of service for the network before you can continue. This page happens to be served as a HTTPS page. Therefore, any time `apt-get` tried to connect, it was ending up at an HTTPS site. This is also why trying to install `apt-transport-https` wasn't working for me.

Comment: That's called a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal).