# E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found

Tags: installation, apt, updates, package-management

I tried using `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https` but it doesn't work for me.

```
sudo apt-get update
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.

sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apt-transport-https is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'apt-transport-https' has no installation candidate
```

My `etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring restricted universe multiverse main #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring-security universe
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/ raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical\'s
## \'partner\' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found." error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165676/how-do-i-fix-a-e-the-method-driver-usr-lib-apt-methods-http-could-not-be-foun)

Comment: Tried the method on that link but I can't make it work.

Comment: all the other methods ?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you run? Can you paste your /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: I'm a newcomer to Linux, please excuse my dumbness. Here's my source list.

http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=rwXaeFMX

Comment: Can you add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your sources.list, I still don't quite understand why `apt` is in need of `https` (maybe some additional sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?), but to get `apt-transport-https` installed you can do this:

```
sudo wget http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt-transport-https_0.9.7.7ubuntu5_$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_ARCH).deb && sudo dpkg -i apt-transport-https_0.9.7.7ubuntu5_$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_ARCH).deb
```

The `dpkg-architecture` command is used to determine the architecture of your system. You could also replace it with `i386` or `amd64`.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get the exact command line variant working, but I was able to browse to

```
http://ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/
```

Where I located the latest version of the apt-transport-https, in my case the

```
apt-transport-https_0.9.7.7ubuntu6_i386.deb
```

I then downloaded it, double clicked the deb file and installed it. Now everything seems to work correctly again.