# "E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/htp could not be found." after removing the LAMP task

Tags: 13.04, lamp, aptitude

So, I tried uninstalling the LAMP stack I had following [the Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Starting_over:_How_to_remove_the_LAMP_stack) for it.  I also manually removed dbconfig-common.

Now, I'm unable to run apt-get update.  When I do, I get the error message:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/htp could not be found.
```

After some digging, I've discovered that I no longer even have an `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Also, I've received an error, when trying to run:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

That aptitude can not be found.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do?  I'm not able to find any documentation online that works - all the documentation out there is dated and no longer (or will not) work with 13.04.

I followed this link previously prior to posting my question and it did not work for me:

- [How do I fix a "E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found." error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165676/how-do-i-fix-a-e-the-method-driver-usr-lib-apt-methods-http-could-not-be-foun)
- When I run `cd /usr/lib/apt/methods` and then run `ls` and it shows that http and https are files that exist within that directory. Not sure why the script that is run when updating looks for the driver in `/methods/htp`

Comment: Can you confirm in your question that `/usr/lib/apt/methods/htp cannot be found` is the error it is telling you? It should be http and not htp, but hopefuly that's a typo.

Comment: to confirm: root@01-K50IJ:~# sudo apt-get update
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/htp could not be found.

Answer (score 3):

You have a corrupted line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or one of the `*.list` files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

For example:

```
$ echo "deb oops://ubuntu.com/ foo bar" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/something.list 
$ apt-get update
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/oops could not be found.
```

Try this command to spot it:

```
$ grep htp: /etc/apt/*.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

Comment: The return is: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:deb htp://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main

Comment: I nano'ed into the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list and corrected the http typo.

Comment: a.  you're smart and b. that's a cool command